# Upload one image but store in 3 location with 3 diffrent size in PHP

Tags: php, function, uploading

I need a php scripts to allow me, upload one image on 3 diffrent location with diffrent size,

1- thumbnail
2- medium
3- large (orginal size)

can anybody help me ?

Comment: What have you tried or searched so far? Put some code in here and you can get help.

Comment: To ask this kind of question on StackOverflow, you must first try doing your own research and attempted solution. You can then ask questions about any specific problems that you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP's built in GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library for such image manipulations or the popular [imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) library.

The process would involve saving the file on server-side, re-sampling it to the 3 desired sizes saving the result of each into a different file.